# How to make ordinary extra-ordinary without juxtaposition?

Tags: street-photography, art

If you ask street photographers what is a good photographer, many of them would say – “something that make ordinary extra-ordinary”. Which is a truth and even many masters would agree with that.

> Edward Weston says "This then: to photograph a rock, have it look like a rock, but be more than a rock. Significant presentation – not interpretation."
>
> Edward Weston  also said  “I see no reason for recording the obvious.”

Many photographers are using juxtaposition to bring this extra-ordinary look. And many a times they become mediocre photographs.

So, what are the other techniques to create the extra-ordinary photographs from ordinary, without using juxtaposition?

**UPDATE**

Following are some of the photos that I feel made extra-ordinary without any juxtaposition. So, what is the techniques in these photos that make it look extra-ordinary?

1. [Rock and Grass, Moraine Lake, Sequoia National Park](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/166633254933599984/)
2. http://www.pinterest.com/pin/166633254933596759/
3. http://www.pinterest.com/pin/166633254933596700/

Comment: By going out, looking and trial-error and not getting philosophical about it.

Comment: I like this kind of question in general. I'd much rather have these rather than a zillion more questions comparing camera bodies and low-cost superzooms. But this one is awfully vague. Can you give a more specific situation, and maybe even an example photograph of your own which you feel _doesn't_ work?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you're asking here... Is this a real question or are you attempting to use the [Socratic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method) to teach?

Comment: There is a single answer non opinion based answer to this question. These images demonstrate an understanding of the elements and principles of design. The techniques are:
Unity/Harmony, Balance, Hierarchy, Scale/Proportion, Dominance/Emphasis, Similarity And Contrast.

Design elements and principles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_elements_and_principles